# ruby on rails website on two language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multilingual

how to make a website in two languages on rails?
use gem or create two projects or register two domains?
help me, please. Link or quick explanation of the ideas as it is accepted to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails Internationalization (I18n) API
  is what you looking for, is already built in Rails no gem needed  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html